# Kafka Stream Restore Consumers not able to authenticate

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am having an issue with restore consumers,  they are not able to connect to the brokers getting :

```
Connection to node -1 failed authentication due to: Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism PLAIN
```

In the ConsumerConfig values: info log for xxx-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer I see no group.id being set.  Non restore consumers such as xxx-StreamThread-1-consumer have a group id being set.

Doing some digging it looks like restore consumers should not have a group id.  Our topics are permission based where our consumers need to be part of a specific consumer group to access a specific topic.

Is there a way to set the group id?  What are these restore consumers?  How do we get pass this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a `group.id` for restore consumers.

Restore consumers are used to (as the name suggests) restore state. For example, if a stateful task migrates from instance A to instance B, before instance B can resume processing it first needs to re-create the state. The restore consumers are used for this part (ie, reading the corresponding store changelog topics).

**Note, that this is a hack—I think it should work, but you apply it on your own risk:** What you could do as a workaround, is to use a custom `KafkaClientSupplier` that you pass into `KafkaStreams` constructor. In `getRestoreConsumer()` before you create a new `KafkaConsumer` you modify the provided `Map<String, Object> config` and add a `group.id` entry.